# "Invalid tag name" error when creating element with lxml in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I am using lxml to make an xml file and my sample program is :

```
from lxml import etree
import datetime
dt=datetime.datetime(2013,11,30,4,5,6)
dt=dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
page=etree.Element('html')
doc=etree.ElementTree(page)
dateElm=etree.SubElement(page,dt)
outfile=open('somefile.xml','w')
doc.write(outfile)
```

And I am getting the following error output :

```
dateElm=etree.SubElement(page,dt)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2899, in lxml.etree.SubElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:62284)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 171, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:14296)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1523, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:26852)
ValueError: Invalid tag name u'2013-11-30'
```

I thought it of a Unicode Error,
so tried changing encoding of **'dt'** with codes like

1. `str(dt)`
2. `unicode(dt).encode('unicode_escape')`
3. `dt.encocde('ascii','ignore')`
4. `dt.encode('ascii','decode')`

and some others also, but none worked and same error msg generated.

Comment: Can you add the relevant fragment of your input XMl?

Comment: ^ my xml file is empty. I am writing output by using the last line of code - 'doc.write(outfile)'

Comment: It seems you are writing out the date as a *tag*. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: ^ ah..yes. I am writing like <date>some value</date>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the error because element names are not allowed to begin with a digit in XML. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags. The first character of a name must be a `NameStartChar`, which disallows digits.

An element such as `<2013-11-30>...</2013-11-30>` is invalid.

An element such as `<D2013-11-30>...</D2013-11-30>` is OK.

If your program is changed to use ElementTree instead of lxml (`from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree` instead of `from lxml import etree`), there is no error. But I would consider that a bug. lxml does the right thing, ElementTree does not.

Comment: I am changing the date element to a string by using str(date) method before inserting it..and I tried the same with 'xml.etree.ElementTree' and it worked fine. May be there is problem with  'lxml' , but I don't know for sure . Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Using `str(dt)` does not help. At that point in the program, `dt` already is a string (the return value of `datetime.strftime()`). lxml is correct when it rejects the `2013-11-30` tag name.

Comment: @j.f.sebastian - It's definitely an error on 'xml.etree.ElementTree' , because even if it saves the 'date' format to 'xml' file, it shows parsing error if I do "xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('somefile.xml')" for the saved file. Adding an extra character to 'date' tag solves the problem. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not about Unicode. There is no `2013-11-30` tag in HTML. You could use `time` tag instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import date
from lxml.html import tostring
from lxml.html.builder import E


datestr = date(2013, 11, 30).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

page = E.html(
    E.title("date demo"),
    E('time', "some value", datetime=datestr))

with open('somefile.html', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(tostring(page, doctype='<!doctype html>', pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: my file is 'xml' , not 'html'. So , I could store anything as tag, given it is str (Correct me if wrong..). My code is working fine if I import 'xml.etree.ElementTree' , I don't know why it's a problem in 'lxml'

Comment: @Chandrakant: 1. don't use the root `html` tag if the document is not actually HTML. It is misleading. 2. As [mzjn said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20304493/4279), `ElementTree` is wrong to accept your input. `lxml` works as defined in XML specification. As you said, your file is 'xml' so it must follow XML specification.