# Extract XML tags with their paths and values to EXCEL

Tags: python, excel, xml

I want to use Python to extract tags and their paths and their values from XML to EXCEL such that the column name is the path of that tag and below it is the value of that tag.

SAMPLE XML INPUT-

```html
<world>
<countries>
    <country>
        <name>a</name>
        <description>a short description</description>
        <population>
            <now>250000</now>
            <2000>100000</2000>
        </population>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>b</name>
        <description>b short description</description>
        <population>
            <now>350000</now>
            <2000>150000</2000>
        </population>
    </country>
</countries>
</world>
```

SAMPLE EXCEL OUTPUT-
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IofCy.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I am able to extract all the tags and their values into Excel so far.
I am stuck at the path part, how to get that in the exact way i have mentioned.

Comment: lxml has `getpath()`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1577293/407651

Comment: Btw, you cannot have an element called `2000`. Element names are not allowed to start with a digit. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20302560/407651.

Comment: @mzjn hey thanks, this worked. After a few workarounds I was able to get the desired output.
And yeah i know 2000 is now allowed, I just copied it from somewhere. Its not my XML.